# How to make the validation error to come right side in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have to make a view where I want to make the validation error come to left side as shown in the image any idea to achieve that and also I want to put validation on multiple text input [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use use FormField Widget for this purpose
Here is an example

```
FormField(validator: (x) {
      //my validation
    }, builder: (formState) {
      return Column(
        children: [
        //my text field
          TextFormField(),
         // if validation fails formState.hasError=true else formState.hasError=false
          if (formState.hasError && formState.errorText != null)
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Text(formState.errorText!),
            )
        ],
      );
    })
```

Comment: Validation is not woking even if there is data in textfield it is giving me error

Comment: can u share me you code

Comment: It doesn't allow long code here